# using my own public and private key for managing wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, wallet

I managed to create wallets for bitcoin with public and private key. I can get the balance of these wallets.

But when I want to send someone tokens from this wallet, I can't because there is no website nor application that will accept my wallet (rather they create wallets on registration or installing the app).

I used Node.js for programming the application and I don't have a full node.

*Please do not answer about security or other stuff just want to know
how I can use this token or transform them to other wallets **without programming**.*

Comment: Which token are you talking about? What's the issue and how is it related to bitcoin?

Comment: Hello @Prayank, both ERC20 tokens and bitcoin I have wallets with balances but I can't spend them or send their tokens to other wallets

Comment: Which wallet and what happens when you try to send bitcoin?

Comment: Since this is a bitcoin-only Q&A website I edited out the parts about ERC20 and other cryptocurrencies. You can restore the previous version if you disagree with my edits, but there is the danger that other people may then close the question as [off-topic](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Prayank the ERC20 now I found a wallet for managing but I want a software to manage my own wallet with my private and public key for bitcoin